# image link start with http: doesn't load

Tags: java, android, http, https

I show images from internet in my app.

when I retrieve image link starts with https:// the app show it, but when image link stats with http:// the image doesn't load.

I display image by using glide

Comment: thanks it works,
but is displaying images from sites stats with http: isn't secure?

Comment: If its just images probably not an issue, but without HTTPS, man-in-the-middle attack is possible for more valuable things (login tokens, passwords, etc.)

Comment: Whether `just images` and `not an issue` should go into one sentence depends on what information these images would contain, what they'd be used for etc.